# How to parse XML input field for specifc value using Oracle Sql?

Tags: sql, xml, oracle11g

I am having difficulty in writing a query that selects data from table (card_type). I need to parse the xml attribute(EXT_PROPERTIES_XML) only where the Name tag has "PARTNER_CD" in it. Below is the sample for the xml attribute.

```
    <Properties>
         <Property>
               <Name>PARTNER_CD</Name>
               <Value>LOBT</Value>
         </Property>
         <Property>
               <Name>REJECT_AT_PUMP</Name>
               <Value>true</Value>
         </Property>
         <Property>
              <Name>MAX_LITRE</Name>
              <Value>75</Value></Property>
    </Properties>

    <Properties>
         <Property>
               <Name>PARTNER_CD</Name>
               <Value>PET1</Value>
         </Property>
         <Property>
               <Name>REJECT_AT_PUMP</Name>
               <Value>true</Value>
         </Property>
         <Property>
              <Name>MAX_LITRE</Name>
              <Value>75</Value></Property>
    </Properties>
```

**Desired Output:**

```
NAME                VALUE
-------------------------
PARTNER_CD          LOBT
PARTNER_CD          PET1
```

This is what I tried..

```
 Select xmltype.createxml(EXT_PROPERTIES_XML).extract('/Properties/Property/Name/text()').getStringVal() as  Name, 
xmltype.createxml(EXT_PROPERTIES_XML).extract('/Properties/Property/Value/text()').getStringVal() as Value
    from card_type
```

**Output that I got was:**

```
           Name                         Value
PARTNER_CDREJECT_AT_PUMPMAX_LITRE       LOBTtrue75
```

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [an XMLQuery or XMLTable](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb_xquery.htm) to extract the data:

```
select x.*
from card_type c
cross join xmltable('/Properties/Property'
  passing xmltype(ext_properties_xml)
  columns name varchar2(20) path 'Name',
    value varchar2(20) path 'Value'
) x
where name = 'PARTNER_CD';

NAME                 VALUE              
-------------------- --------------------
PARTNER_CD           LOBT                
PARTNER_CD           PET1
```